Slurm only running 1 job per node
I'm building a new slurm cluster, and I'm not very familiar with how resources are allocated. I have 4 nodes with 32 cores each. When I submit jobs, it only runs 1 job per node, and the rest are in a pending state.
All of the jobs should be single threaded and occupy only one core. How can I get the other jobs to run? Each node should be able to run 32 simultaneously. Below is the output of squeue:
         JOBID PARTITION     NAME     USER ST       TIME  NODES NODELIST(REASON)
           249  computes freesurf     nidb PD       0:00      1 (Resources)
           250  computes freesurf     nidb PD       0:00      1 (Priority)
           251  computes freesurf     nidb PD       0:00      1 (Priority)
           252  computes freesurf     nidb PD       0:00      1 (Priority)
           253  computes freesurf     nidb PD       0:00      1 (Priority)
           254  computes freesurf     nidb PD       0:00      1 (Priority)
           255  computes freesurf     nidb PD       0:00      1 (Priority)
           256  computes freesurf     nidb PD       0:00      1 (Priority)
           257  computes freesurf     nidb PD       0:00      1 (Priority)
           258  computes freesurf     nidb PD       0:00      1 (Priority)
           259  computes freesurf     nidb PD       0:00      1 (Priority)
           260  computes freesurf     nidb PD       0:00      1 (Priority)
           261  computes freesurf     nidb PD       0:00      1 (Priority)
           262  computes freesurf     nidb PD       0:00      1 (Priority)
           263  computes freesurf     nidb PD       0:00      1 (Priority)
           245  computes freesurf     nidb  R       8:00      1 compute60
           246  computes freesurf     nidb  R       7:40      1 compute61
           247  computes freesurf     nidb  R       7:19      1 compute62
           248  computes freesurf     nidb  R       6:55      1 compute63

And the Node and Partition from slurm.conf
NodeName=compute60 NodeAddr=10.35.10.110 CPUs=64 Boards=1 SocketsPerBoard=2 CoresPerSocket=16 ThreadsPerCore=2 RealMemory=515827 State=UNKNOWN
NodeName=compute61 NodeAddr=10.35.10.111 CPUs=64 Boards=1 SocketsPerBoard=2 CoresPerSocket=16 ThreadsPerCore=2 RealMemory=515827 State=UNKNOWN
NodeName=compute62 NodeAddr=10.35.10.112 CPUs=64 Boards=1 SocketsPerBoard=2 CoresPerSocket=16 ThreadsPerCore=2 RealMemory=515827 State=UNKNOWN
NodeName=compute63 NodeAddr=10.35.10.113 CPUs=64 Boards=1 SocketsPerBoard=2 CoresPerSocket=16 ThreadsPerCore=2 RealMemory=515827 State=UNKNOWN

PartitionName=computes Nodes=compute60,compute61,compute62,compute63 Default=NO MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP


I figured out the issue. There were two things wrong:

I needed to add SelectTypeParameters=CR_Core to the slurm.conf
I needed to specify the memory in the job submission file. If it was left blank, slurm would assume the job needed all of the RAM for the node, and thus would not allow any other jobs to run because the node was assumed to have no memory available


Setting a DefMemPerCPU in your node definitions might be handy.  Two potential options are "total memory / cores" or "half of total memory / cores". The former is a useful default but it's a good assumption that people will NEVER ask for less than default.  The latter lets people who know they need more memory "burst" higher.
My cluster sets def, min and max all to "memory / cores" - we don't let people select RAM, only cores.  That makes things "easy" but restricts some job types from fitting in more closely

Make sure the SelectType option has value select/cons_tres in the slurm.conf configuration file. See more information in the documentation page about Consumable Resources in Slurm

Looks like that value was already set in the slurm.conf
